# SQL DEVELOPER script output formatting

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: My script output]

There seems to be a line break after every 11 entries in my script output in SQL developer. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Developer output use same format as `SQL*Plus`.

you can use `SHOW ALL` command to view all availables format setting.

You can try your own fitness by changing `PAGESIZE` value.

Comment: Correct. Default pagesize is 11.

Comment: set pagesize 0
select line from user_source; -- execute F5 for quick sanity check